# What does "this design sucks like an inverted hurricane" mean?

Tags: idioms

Martin Fowler in [his Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture says](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vqTfNFDzzdIC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=%22sucks%20like%20an%20inverted%20hurricane%22&source=bl&ots=oSDnBrNUsx&sig=Z_zw7O88RxyoM4Zn5tpjLNHLgIg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAWoVChMIp_bki-GKyQIVpPxyCh29fwp8#v=onepage&q=%22sucks%20like%20an%20inverted%20hurricane%22&f=false): "*this design sucks like an inverted hurricane*". I can't get the last part. What does the "inverted hurricate" mean in this context? Or is this an untranslatable idiom?

Comment: It's a simile; it hasn't reached 'idiom' status (yet?) with only about 50 Google hits.

Answer (score 4):

A hurricane is a vast spinning storm that produces powerful winds that blow out from its centrifugal force.  This is the opposite of something that sucks things into itself.  To get a storm that sucked (literally), you'd need the opposite (figuratively) of a hurricane.  Which would be an inverted (totally turned inside out) hurricane.

Comment: Fowler's metaphor is strained like a pulled groin muscle.

Comment: @TimRomano He is a big joker actually ;) Sometimes he sounds sardonic in his book. BTW, I am not really sure its him because different chapters of the book were written by different people. But when you read, narrator feels the almost the same.

Comment: Though technically a hurricane sucks too.  The eye has extremely low pressure, and this is what drives it.  So it's unclear why it needs to be "inverted".

Comment: Yes, As  Edwin Ashworth commented, it's a simile. However it is a very poor one.  An inverted hurricane wouldn't suck (or blow) any more than a non-inverted one. In fact it would rapidly peter out due to the coriolis force opposing its direction of spin. In the Southern hemisphere a 'hurricane' spins in the opposite direction and is called a cyclone -- cyclones are typically weak in comparison.

Comment: Perhaps the simile sucks worse than the proposed hurricane, but it's best not to take *Inverted* too literally to mean opposite chirality but reverse effect, basically a large tornado.